# importing xxx as a folder when xxx is package

Tags: python, import, package, directory, equals

Assume I got a directory, which consist of a folder having some python scripts.

I want to import the folder to get the functions in those python scripts.

If I am at the same directory, I can `import folder_name`.

But problem starts, when `folder_name = actual_python_package_name`.

**e.g.:**

your folders name is numpy, `import numpy` imports the lib.

Any way to make python to choose the folder instead of the package while importing?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you come from one step back in your directories :
for example from previous_folder.your_main_folder import your_function 
should be work maybe.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `__init__.py` to your folder to turn it into a python package, it should be imported instead of other python libraries. The order is determined by `sys.path`.
But why not simply avoid name collisions?

Comment: well, easiest option would be avoiding name collisions, I did it too in my code. But I was wondering if someway exists without changing the folder name

Comment: But if you have a package (with `__init__.py`) in your working directory, it does take precedence over packages installed elsewhere. So you can import your scripts, but not the installed package with the same name.